# Get service name inside service

Tags: c#, winapi, powershell, service, permissions

I want to get service name inside service. The rough idea is to get process id and compare the  process id with services enumerated by WMI, ServiceCotroller or EnumServicesStatusEx() API.

The problem is that the service is running under a domain account (it isn't local administrator). When I want to enumerate the services inside the running service, the running service itself is missing from enumeration!

If I move the service account to local administrator, the running service is found. So it isn't code issue. (If code issue, the behavior should be same: service not found.)

If I extract the logic to a console application (or by powershell) and run application or powershell under service account, the service is found, too. So it isn't permission issue. (If permission issue, the behavior should be same: service not found.)

The service CANNOT be enumerated when the service account IS NOT administrator and INSIDE service. It is very wire issue.

I check documentation for EnumServicesStatusEx from MSDN and find local administrator has extra SC_MANAGER_LOCK than local authenticated user. Is it the reason? But I CANNOT link the lock with service enumeration.

Or somebody please indicate a way to query service name inside the service.

Thanks.

BTW, It is on Windows 2008 R2.

I found a related question: [How to get name of windows service from inside the service itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773678/how-to-get-name-of-windows-service-from-inside-the-service-itself).
the [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/775090/1828478) is not acceptable for me. I want to provide a common library and has no control to installer.
the [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6225066/1828478) is same idea with me. I guess it should be same with my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **permission** issue.

Run psservice from Sysinternals like:

```
psservice.exe security InstrumentationTestService
```

and I got the following result:

```
PsService v2.24 - Service information and configuration utility
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SERVICE_NAME: InstrumentationTestService
DISPLAY_NAME: InstrumentationTestService
        ACCOUNT: LocalSystem
        SECURITY:
        [ALLOW] NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
                Query status
                Query Config
                Interrogate
                Enumerate Dependents
                Pause/Resume
                Start
                Stop
                User-Defined Control
                Read Permissions
        [ALLOW] BUILTIN\Administrators
                All
        [ALLOW] NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
                Query status
                Query Config
                Interrogate
                Enumerate Dependents
                User-Defined Control
                Read Permissions
        [ALLOW] NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE
                Query status
                Query Config
                Interrogate
                Enumerate Dependents
                User-Defined Control
                Read Permissions
```

It indicates that my service account has no permission to Query the service status.

If I use service account to run powershell/WMI/ServiceController, the service account will turn into a INTERACTIVE user. So it has the permission to query service status.

The solution is to grant the service account Query status permission.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure PowerShell answer, but you've got a good tool as far as EXEs,DLLs and SERVICEs are concerned it's [TASKLIST.EXE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx).

Have a look to /FI and /FO. In the following sample I get information for the search service.

```
tasklist /FI "SERVICES eq WSearch" /FO "CSV"
```

To integrate it with PowerShell youcan use :

```
tasklist /FI "SERVICES eq WSearch" /FO "CSV" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get service PID and try to run tasklist like: tasklist /FI "PID eq {PID}" /SVC /NH. It returns service name is *N/A*. BTW, if I run tasklist in powershell with service account, it can return the correct service name. So your solution is failed. too.

Comment: Are you sure to call it correctly ? Can you give the exact syntax you use ?

Comment: `tasklist /FI "PID eq 2524" /SVC`  return "sqlservr.exe                  2524 MSSQLSERVER" in console  return "sqlservr.exe                  2524 N/A" in service debug output  So wired.

Comment: Do you try to run your service in elevated mode ?